# .repeatForever() does not work when value is updated in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui, offset

I'm trying to make an idle animation in `SwiftUI` that gets triggered if there's no touch in the screen for 3 seconds. I made a little animation that goes up and down (y offset 15) when there's no touch for 3 seconds and goes back to its original position when a touch occurs. But the thing is, when it goes to its original positon, autoreverses doesn't get triggered. Here's how it looks like:

[image: hmm]

Go Live button:

```swift
struct GoLiveButton: View {

  @State private var animationOffset: CGFloat = 0
  @Binding var isIdle: Bool

  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Button(action: {} ) {
        Text("Go Live")
          .frame(width: 120, height: 40)
          .background(Color.black)
          .foregroundColor(.white)
          .clipShape(Capsule())
          .font(.system(size: 20))
          .shadow(color: .black, radius: 4, x: 4, y: 4)
      }
      .offset(y: animationOffset)
      .animation(.timingCurve(0.38, 0.07, 0.12, 0.93, duration: 2).repeatForever(autoreverses: true), value: isIdle)
      .animation(.timingCurve(0.38, 0.07, 0.12, 0.93, duration: 2), value: !isIdle)
    }
    .onAppear {
      self.isIdle = true
      self.animationOffset = 15
    }
    .onChange(of: isIdle) { newValue in
      if newValue {
        self.animationOffset = 15
      }
      else {
        self.animationOffset = 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the idle view:

```
struct StackOverflowView: View {

  @State private var timer: Timer?
  @State private var isIdle = false

  var body: some View {

    GeometryReader { geo in
      GoLiveButton(isIdle: $isIdle)
    }
    .onTapGesture {
      print("DEBUG: CustomTabView OnTapGesture Triggered")
      self.isIdle = false
      self.timer?.invalidate()
      self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: false) { _ in
        self.isIdle = true
      }
    }
    .gesture(
      DragGesture().onEnded { _ in
        self.isIdle = false
        self.timer?.invalidate()
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: false) { _ in
          self.isIdle = true
        }
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your problem. I pasted both codes into ContentView.swift that auto creates with a new project, then created a GoLiveButton(). Got an error that was missing a parameters in the call. So I added GoLiveButton(isIdle: $isIdle). Then I got an error that this variable was not declared (of course), so I added to ContentView a new instance State private var isIdle = false. No problem in the animation after that.

Comment: My guess is that I broke your logic by changing that, making the "state" never reaches a idle state.

Comment: I don't have the time to do it now, so I'll not say this as an answer. But you need a AnimatableModifier that saves the position of the state in the AnimatableData of the Protocol. So when it resumes the animation it starts from where it was. Also I guess will play nicer with autoreverse. You animation is "jumping" because animations in swift are instant in the variables it animates, only the visuals are animated, not that the value are changing over time. So when it "resume" the idle animation it resume from start value. If you put this into an AnimatableViewModifier will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach without AnimatableData:

I added a second timer that just triggers the animations by offset (0, -15, 0, -15 ...) every 2 seconds, repeating forever.

If `isIdle` changes to false, we just set offset to 0, and this will be animated too. We reset all timers. And again set the idle timer (3 secs) which when fires will start the animation timer (2 secs). voila.

(I also restructured the `GoLiveButton` a little bit so it holds all relevant states in itself, and the parent view only has to control `isIdle`)

```
struct GoLiveButton: View {
    
    @Binding var isIdle: Bool
    @State private var timer: Timer?
    @State private var animationTimer: Timer?
    @State private var animationOffset: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button(action: {} ) {
                Text("Go Live")
                    .frame(width: 120, height: 40)
                    .background(Color.black)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .clipShape(Capsule())
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                    .shadow(color: .black, radius: 4, x: 4, y: 4)
            }
            .offset(y: animationOffset)
            .animation(.timingCurve(0.38, 0.07, 0.12, 0.93, duration: 2), value: animationOffset)
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: false) { _ in
                self.isIdle = true
                animationTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: true) { _ in
                    animationOffset = (animationOffset == 15) ? 0 : 15
                }
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: isIdle) { newValue in
            if newValue == false {
                // reset all
                self.animationTimer?.invalidate()
                self.timer?.invalidate()
                animationOffset = 0
                
                self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: false) { _ in
                    self.isIdle = true
                    animationTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: true) { _ in
                        animationOffset = (animationOffset == 15) ? 0 : 15
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isIdle = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            // for background tap only
            Color.gray.opacity(0.2)
                .onTapGesture {
                    print("tap")
                    self.isIdle = false
                }
            
            GoLiveButton(isIdle: $isIdle)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My god you're a hero without a cape

Comment: but this time I am encountering an issue with the `.onTapGesture` in my root view. When I use it, it prevents me from being able to tap any other subviews. Do you have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: the `.onTagGesture` in my code is only dummy to show activity. You can skip this and set isIdle in your root view. If you still can't tap subviews you might try `.simultaneousGesture` or the `DragGesture` you already had (with distance:0).